# Port 25 not open, how send email?

Tags: email, dns

I have client that email is ######@example.com

I tried to send email, but it does not work

I ran `dig` against example.com

```
example.com.                        IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.         14399   IN      MX      0 example.com.
```

and found a valid MX record for it.

However I scanned example.com, but port 25 was not open

How can I send mail to example.com in that case?

Comment: @ivanivan: Other protocols can use DNS SRV records, which _do_ send a port number, although it's true that MX records used by email don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really cannot send mail to this domain if none of their MX hosts is listening on port 25.

However, what probably happened here is that your ISP blocks *your* outbound access to port 25 outside of their own network. This is basically the case everywhere; if you need outbound port 25, you need to be in a dedicated netblock, and probably pay more than you do for consumer broadband.

Your ISP's mail server will obviously have outbound access to port 25, and you should be able to use it as the relay host for your own outgoing mail.

Some services allow individual (usually authenticated) users to *submit* email on port 587 or 465, but to run an MX server, you need for it to listen on port 25.

Comment: Practically - if its not *his* server, and its the *client's* server - the client needs to sort it out ;p.